# Google Chart dashboard multiple data

Tags: javascript, visualization, dashboard, google-visualization

I created a google chart dashboard with different data for each donut chart but only data_2 returns, instead of data_1 for the first chart `<div>` and data_2 for the second chart `<div>`. [Source document](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_multiple_charts) for multi chart w/ different data requires separate functions, but is there a way to use two datasets in the first function drawStuff_1?
I ultimately want one dashboard, one ControlWrapper (one-to-many), multiple data sets (carlos, josh, etc.) and multiple donut charts (`<div>` for carlos, `<div>` for josh, whoever else).

```html
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff_1);
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff_2);

      function drawStuff_1() {

        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
          document.getElementById('programmatic_dashboard_div'));
          
        programmaticFilter_1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'programmatic_control_div_1',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Status',
            'ui': {'labelStacking': 'vertical'}
          }
        });
    // First dataset
       var data_1 = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Status', 'Count'],
        ['Dual Approved' , 5],
        ['Approved', 7],
        ['Review', 3],
        ['Draft', 2],
        ['Not In', 6],
        ['Edit Rerun', 1],
        ]);
       programmaticChart_1  = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'PieChart',
        'containerId': 'programmatic_chart_div_1',
        'options': {
          'width': 290,
          'height': 220,
          'chartArea': {'left': 20, 'top': 20, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0},
          'pieSliceText': 'value', //percentage' 'value' 'label''none'
          'pieHole': 0.4,
          'legend': {position: 'left', textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 9, fontName: 'Garamond' }},
          'pieSliceBorderColor': 'Black',
          'title': 'Josh',
          
        }
      });

      dashboard.bind(programmaticFilter_1, programmaticChart_1);
      dashboard.draw(data_1);

    }
    
   function drawStuff_2() {

        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
          document.getElementById('programmatic_dashboard_div'));
          
// second dataset      
           var data_2 = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Status', 'Count'],
        ['Dual Approved' , 1],
        ['Approved', 10],
        ['Review', 2],
        ['Draft', 9],
        ['Not In', 10],
        ['Edit Rerun', 4],
        ]);
        
       programmaticChart_2  = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'PieChart',
        'containerId': 'programmatic_chart_div_2',
        'options': {
          'width': 250,
          'height': 220,
          'legend': 'none',
          'chartArea': {'left': 20, 'top': 20, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0},
          'pieSliceText': 'value', //percentage' 'value' 'label''none'
          'pieHole': 0.4,
          'pieSliceBorderColor': 'Black',
          'title': 'Carlos',
        }
      });

      dashboard.bind(programmaticFilter_1, programmaticChart_2);
      dashboard.draw(data_2);
}
    </script>
 
  <body>
    <div id="programmatic_dashboard_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
                <td>
            <div id="programmatic_control_div_1" style="padding-left: 2em; min-width: 250px"></div>
          </td>
      <table class="columns">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div id="programmatic_chart_div_1"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="programmatic_chart_div_2"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first, `setOnLoadCallback` should only be used once per page

but it's an easy work around, and you can include the `callback` directly in the `load` statement

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawStuff,
  packages:['corechart', 'controls']
});
```

next, you can only have one *dataset* per `Dashboard`

however, you can use the `view` property on the `ChartWrapper`
to control which columns, or rows, apply to the chart

the `view` property is also available on the `ControlWrapper`

see following working snippet, which includes one dashboard, one control,
and two charts *(one for each Carlos and Josh)*

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawStuff,
  packages:['corechart', 'controls']
});

function drawStuff() {
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard_div')
  );

  // Combined dataset
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Status', 'Carlos', 'Josh'],
    ['Dual Approved', 5, 1],
    ['Approved', 7, 10],
    ['Review', 3, 2],
    ['Draft', 2, 9],
    ['Not In', 6, 10],
    ['Edit Rerun', 1, 3]
  ]);

  var programmaticFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'control_div',
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Status',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical'
      }
    }
  });

  var programmaticChart_Carlos = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div_Carlos',
    options: {
      width: 290,
      height: 220,
      chartArea: {'left': 20, 'top': 20, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0},
      pieSliceText: 'value',
      pieHole: 0.4,
      legend: {position: 'left', textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 9, fontName: 'Garamond' }},
      pieSliceBorderColor: 'Black'
    },
    view: {
      columns: [0, 1]
    }
  });
  programmaticChart_Carlos.setOption('title', 'Carlos');

  var programmaticChart_Josh = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div_Josh',
    options: {
      width: 290,
      height: 220,
      chartArea: {'left': 20, 'top': 20, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0},
      pieSliceText: 'value',
      pieHole: 0.4,
      legend: {position: 'left', textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 9, fontName: 'Garamond' }},
      pieSliceBorderColor: 'Black'
    },
    view: {
      columns: [0, 2]
    }
  });
  programmaticChart_Josh.setOption('title', 'Josh');

  dashboard.bind(
    programmaticFilter,
    [programmaticChart_Carlos, programmaticChart_Josh]
  );
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```css
.ggl-dashboard {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.ggl-control (
  min-width: 250px;
  padding-left: 2em;
)

.ggl-chart (
  display: inline-block;
)
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div class="ggl-dashboard" id="dashboard_div">
  <div class="ggl-control" id="control_div"></div>
  <div class="ggl-chart" id="chart_div_Carlos"></div>
  <div class="ggl-chart" id="chart_div_Josh"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, yes I considered combining datasets but was too stubborn thinking there was a way, lol. Thank you WhiteHat, very helpful!

Comment: Thank you so much, this view columns option was exactly what i was looking for but having great trouble finding that existed... google docs not the best